# Glassfish OpenSSO instructions (where to download OpenSSO)?

Tags: java, oracle, glassfish, saml, opensso

According to the [tutorial](http://developers.sun.com/identity/reference/techart/opensso-glassfish.html), I should go to OpenSSO and download an "express build".  However, the download links on the OpenSSO site for the "Express Build 7" appear to require logging in via an account with a paid support contract.

How can one currently download the OpenSSO wars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try [OpenAM](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Oracle-kills-OpenSSO-Express-ForgeRock-steps-in-939634.html).

I also noticed this.. http://download.java.net/general/opensso/webstartnew/ which will download the bits for testing.  And guess what... there is an opensso.war and the like 'in there' that were produced about the same time as the tutorial was written.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned 
Go and see http://www.forgerock.com/ they provide support and downloads for OpenSSO as OpenAM

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o5ifx4euPw

Also http://www.axiomatics.com/ is a good replacement.

Answer (score 5):

Seems when Oracle bought SUN the links from the open source projects got linked to nowhere. 
Finally I got it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/101401-099957.html

Alternatively you can search on the oracle website for oracle_opensso_80U2.zip

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the exact problem. The builds are not available for free download. I assume it's all because of Sun merger with Oracle. Now I'm worried one day I may have to pay for JDK!!